# Point Sprockets' `depend_on` directive to a non-assets file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have an `app/assets/javascripts/moufa.js.erb` file that gets populated with values from a `config/moufa.yml` file. I want to use the `depend_on` sprockets directive so that every time the yaml file gets changed, it recompiles the js file.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem.  If you use an absolute path, you can point depend_on outside the assets path, but if you use a relative path, Hike explicitly checks to see if the path is one of the asset paths.  I do not (yet) have a solution to this.

Answer (score 7):

We were able to solve this by adding a new directive.  This directive (put this in config/initializers/sprockets.rb) adds a dependency on a file in the config/ directory:

```
class Sprockets::DirectiveProcessor
  def process_depend_on_config_directive(file)
    path = File.expand_path(file, "#{Rails.root}/config")
    context.depend_on(path)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you provide a usage example of this directive?

Comment: //= depend_on_config "application.yml"

Comment: Sound good. I will try it out and confirm if this is working.

Comment: confirmed on sprockets 2.2.2 and rails 3.2

Comment: Failing silently on Rails 4.1.8, Sprockets 2.11.3