# Prevent Rails 4 Sprocket Asset Pipeline from caching a specific file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have a file `globals.css.scss.erb` which only contains:

```
<%= Styles.output %>
```

`Styles` is a custom module to output formatted SCSS/SASS global variables based on a YAML file.

My issue is that when I change the YAML file, `globals.css` does not get updated (i.e., it's cached by Sprockets).

**I want to disable caching on `globals.css`, not all of my assets.  Is this possible?**  This only has to work for my development environment.

Thanks,

Erik

P.S., There is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731329/rails-asset-pipeline-how-to-prevent-caching-of-a-specific-asset) which does not solve the issue.

Comment: Perhaps the approach in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710569/point-sprockets-depend-on-directive-to-a-non-assets-file) may provide some inspiration (even if it apparently does not work as is with rails 4.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understood, you need always to recompile .erb assets. Here is the solution:

```
Sprockets::Asset.class_eval do
  alias_method :orig_dependency_fresh?, :dependency_fresh?
  def dependency_fresh?(environment, dep)
    if dep.pathname.extname.eql? '.erb'
      false
    else
      orig_dependency_fresh?(environment, dep)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @intale, I will try this.  Where's the preferred place to add this?  As an initializer?

Comment: This works and I've marked you as correct.  Thank you.  Although since all of my (many) SCSS files import `globals.css.scss.erb`, it gets recompiled each time (as expected)... but it's too slow.  Do you know of any way to recompile that specific file once "per initial request" then cache thereafter?

Comment: [Here's what I currently have](https://gist.github.com/eriknomitch/bbbd6d23536297627c1e).

Comment: where did you put this? @ErikNomitch I get the following error: `'alias_method': undefined method 'dependency_fresh?' for class 'Sprockets::Asset`

Comment: @LalitKapoor I put it at `lib/styles.rb` and autoload `lib/`.